# Problem with uploading custom font with Custom Fields in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made 1 field with 2 subfields in Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

1st subfield should be for font file upload.
2nd subfield should be for entering my custom text that will be displayed in font file from 1st subfield.

```
<?php
function so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode2() {
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
     $img = get_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', true);
     $text = get_post_meta($id, 'text_input', true);
     $texz='';
     if(!empty($text)){
        $texz=$text;
     }else{
        $texz='Text coming from Static resource';
     }
     if(!empty($img)){
     $url= $img['url'];
 }
    $font_title = get_field("font_title");
    $upload_file = the_sub_field("upload_file");
    $title_name = the_sub_field("title_name");

?>


<style type="text/css">
 @font-face {
font-family: "<?php echo $title_name; ?>";
src: url('<?php echo $upload_file; ?>') format("opentype");
}
</style>

     <input type="text" class="font-input" id="font-input-<?php echo $title_name;?>" value="<?php echo $product->get_title();?>" style="font-family:<?php echo $title_name;?>;font-size: 120px;">

    <?php
}
add_shortcode( 'my_new_shortcode2', 'so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode2' );
```

I want to upload custom font with it and assign some name for it and publish it on my page, but I'm having some issue apparently. I made (edited some existing) shortcode for functions.php that doesn't displays font in uploaded file (it displays it now in system font instead).

What I'm doing wrong?